# How To Convert The DataTable Column type?

Tags: c#, datatable, column-types

I am trying to implement:

```
dtGroupedBy.Compute("sum(POWER)",dvv.RowFilter);
```

It results of an error:

> Invalid usage of aggregate function Sum() and Type: String.

How would we convert it to its column type ??

Comment: can you post the exact error that you're getting, NOT you're interpretation of the error

Comment: @Tarun i am getting this error (Invalid usage of aggregate function Sum() and Type: String.)

Comment: Have you resolved your problem with @Deepak solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute method supports expressions and they support the `CONVERT function` that you could use inside of the expression.

For example, you could calculate sum of the column like

```
MyDataTable.Compute("Sum(Convert(your column name, 'Data Type'))")
```

Comment: I can't use your code... Exception: "Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier."

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on how you've created the `DataTable`. If it's just straight from SQL, you should look into changing the SQL itself so that the POWER column is converted as you fetch it.

However, if the value should always be numeric in the first place, I would strongly suggest that you revisit your database schema - it would be cleaner to change the column type if you possible can.

Comment: actually i am filling this table from the data i am getting from a particular link through internet in XML format

Comment: @Syed: Is it a serialized datatable? Or is it arbitrary XML which you're converting yourself?

Comment: i am getting this data in bytes then encode it in string format  and then i save it in XML format

Comment: @Syed: But what generates this XML in the first place, and how are you converting the XML to a DataTable?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `Sum()` aggregate function on a string field.

There are 2 things you can do

- Redefine your existing column item in your db
  (or schema) to be a numeric field.(recommended)
- do a `System.Int32` conversion on the data you're passing to the aggregate function.
  so you could do the following

> dtGroupedBy.Compute("sum(CONVERT(" +
>   POWER +
>   ",'System.Int32'))",dvv.RowFilter);