# How to change type datatable column

Tags: c#, types, datatable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Convert The DataTable Column type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567787/how-to-convert-the-datatable-column-type)

How can we change the datatable column type if table already have value?

Comment: I guess you could do it with some of this "SQL" code.

Comment: add a new column, update it with the values of the old one (using some kind of conversions if necessary), then delete the old column

Comment: datatable where in the database or in datasets?

Answer (score 14):

Changing data type of datatable after get filled is not possible but one of the work abound for this is clone datatable and change type

**First way**

```
//clone datatable     
DataTable dtCloned = dt.Clone();
//change data type of column
dtCloned.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(Int32);
//import row to cloned datatable
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
{
    dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
}
```

---

**second way**

and other way to do it is like this , fill schema first - than change column datatype and than fill datable

```
adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Source);
table.Columns[0].DataType = typeof (Int32);
adapter.Fill(table);
```

---

**third way**

one more way to do it is

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(int));
dt.Rows.Add(1);

System.Data.DataTable dt2 = new System.Data.DataTable();
dt2.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
dt2.Load(dt.CreateDataReader(), System.Data.LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that second way is worked for mine when I have get Data from database, and before populating in DataTable I have set adapter.FillSchema. like

using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, Con))
                    {
                        dataAdapter.FillSchema(DataTable, SchemaType.Source);
                        DataTable.Columns[9].DataType = typeof(string);
                        dataAdapter.Fill(DataTable);
                    }